# How to type module default getter in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, svg, esmodules

I am building an icon library for future use in React component library. I have an `IconFlag` component which should accept one of the flag icons svg.

Icons svg are in `./icons/flags` folder exported from `index.ts` like this:

```js
export * as AD from "./ad.svg";
...
export * as ZW from "./zw.svg";
```

Then I import them in the `IconFlag` component itself and extract type union:

```js
import * as flags from "./icons/flags";
type IconFlagNames = keyof typeof flags;
```

Now I want to access default value of module exports in my component and this is the part, that gives me a warning `unable to validate computed reference to imported namespace 'flags'`:

```js
export const IconFlag = ({ name }: IconFlagNames ) => {
  const icon = flags[name].default;

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

How do I type this correctly?

upd: This error obviously comes from eslint rule `import/namespace`, tried adding `/*eslint import/namespace: ['error', { allowComputed: true }]*/` but with no success.